# Error: node-canvas was built without JPEG support

Tags: jpeg, apple-m1, node-canvas

/Users/demo/canvas/node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js:91
SetSource.call(img, src);
^

```
Error: node-canvas was built without JPEG support
at setSource (/Users/demo/canvas/node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js:91:13)
at Image.set (/Users/demo/canvas/node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js:62:9)
at /Users/demo/canvas/node_modules/canvas/index.js:34:15
at new Promise ()
at loadImage (/Users/demo/canvas/node_modules/canvas/index.js:23:10)
at Object. (/Users/demo/canvas/index.js:19:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
```

```
    const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas')
    const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.font = '30px Impact'
    ctx.rotate(0.1)
    ctx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100)
    var text = ctx.measureText('Awesome!')
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.lineTo(50, 102)
    ctx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102)
    ctx.stroke()
    loadImage('./2.jpg').then((image) => {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 0, 70, 70)
    
      console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />')
    })
```

**Environment:**
*canvas@2.7.0*
*noede@15.14.0*
*macOS Big Sur 11.1*
*MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)*
*Apple M1*

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. Luckily there has been a fix for that on 11 Nov 2021 (11 days ago).

**EDIT (25th Jan, 2022):**

A new canvas version (2.9.0) has been released, so the issue should not occur anymore.

```
npm install canvas@2.9.0
```

**ORIGNAL ANWSER:**

Just run the following command to install canvas directly from Github. This commit is (today) the most recent commit to master and fixes this issue explicitly.

```
npm install canvas@github:Automattic/node-canvas#198080580a0e3938c48daae357b88a1638a9ddcd
```

The commit:

- https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/commit/198080580a0e3938c48daae357b88a1638a9ddcd

Additional sources I have used:

- https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/pull/1910
- https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1782

Some other people suggested to also set some ENV variables, but this wasn't necessary in my case. I use MacBook Pro with (Apple M1 Pro).

Another things I had to do was installing canvas dependencies to build canvas from source (you probably already did this):

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg libjpeg-turbo
```